# How to center text in a custom arc shape in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, geometry, shapes, text-alignment

I want to center `textView` in `ArcShape`, currently `textView`'s startAngle is set to `ArcShape`'s startAngle. So far, I've tried finding the midpoint of the `ArcShape`'s startAngle and endAngle, but this shifts the `textView` to the right of the `ArcShape`.

How do I calculate the `startAngle` of the `textView` so that it centered in the `ArcShape`?

This is what it looks like currently:

[image]

Ideally, I want it to look like this:

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var letterWidths: [Int: Double] = [:]
    let size: CGFloat = 300

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ArcShape(startAngle: Angle(degrees: 180), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 230))
                .foregroundColor(.green)
            textView("HELLO", startAngle: Angle(degrees: 180))

            ArcShape(startAngle: Angle(degrees: 233), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 300))
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            textView("BYEBYE", startAngle: Angle(degrees: 233))
        }
        .frame(width: size, height: size)
        .frame(height: size / 2)
        .offset(y: size / 4.5)
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func textView(_ title: String, startAngle: Angle) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(Array(title.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, letter in
                VStack {
                    Text(String(letter))
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold, design: .monospaced))
                        .kerning(2)
                        .background(
                            GeometryReader { geometry in // using this to get the width of EACH letter
                                Color.clear
                                    .preference(
                                        key: LetterWidthPreferenceKey.self,
                                        value: geometry.size.width
                                    )
                            }
                        )
                        .onPreferenceChange(LetterWidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { width in
                            letterWidths[index] = width
                        })
                    Spacer()
                }
                .rotationEffect(fetchAngle(at: index))
            }
            .frame(width: size, height: size * 0.75)
            .rotationEffect(startAngle + .degrees(90))
        }
    }

    func fetchAngle(at letterPosition: Int) -> Angle {
        let timesPi: (Double) -> Double = { $0 * .pi }

        let radius: Double = 125
        let circumference = timesPi(radius)

        let finalAngle = timesPi(
            letterWidths
                .filter { $0.key <= letterPosition }
                .map(\.value)
                .reduce(0, +) / circumference
        )

        return .radians(finalAngle)
    }

}

struct LetterWidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: Double = 0
    static func reduce(value: inout Double, nextValue: () -> Double) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

private struct ArcShape: Shape {
    let startAngle: Angle?
    let endAngle: Angle?

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let shorterLength = min(rect.width, rect.height)

        let path = UIBezierPath(
            roundedArcCenter: rect.center,
            innerRadius: (shorterLength / 2) * 0.54,
            outerRadius: (shorterLength / 2) * 0.90,
            startAngle: startAngle ?? .zero,
            endAngle: endAngle ?? .zero,
            cornerRadiusPercentage: 0.01
        )
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}

extension UIBezierPath {
    public convenience init(roundedArcCenter center: CGPoint, innerRadius: CGFloat, outerRadius: CGFloat, startAngle: Angle, endAngle: Angle, cornerRadiusPercentage: CGFloat) {
        let maxCornerRadiusBasedOnInnerArcLength = abs((endAngle - startAngle).radians) * innerRadius / 2
        let maxCornerRadiusBasedOnOuterArcLength = abs((endAngle - startAngle).radians) * outerRadius / 2
        let maxCornerRadiusBasedOnEndCapLength = (outerRadius - innerRadius) / 2
        let outerCornerRadius = min(2 * .pi * outerRadius * cornerRadiusPercentage, maxCornerRadiusBasedOnOuterArcLength, maxCornerRadiusBasedOnEndCapLength)
        let outerCornerRadiusPercentage = outerCornerRadius / (2 * .pi * outerRadius)
        let innerCornerRadius = min(2 * .pi * innerRadius * outerCornerRadiusPercentage, maxCornerRadiusBasedOnInnerArcLength, maxCornerRadiusBasedOnEndCapLength)
        let innerInsetAngle = Angle(radians: innerCornerRadius / innerRadius)
        let outerInsetAngle = Angle(radians: outerCornerRadius / outerRadius)
        self.init()
        var arcStartAngle = (startAngle + outerInsetAngle).radians
        var arcEndAngle = (endAngle - outerInsetAngle).radians
        addArc(
            withCenter: .zero,
            radius: outerRadius,
            startAngle: min(arcStartAngle, arcEndAngle),
            endAngle: max(arcStartAngle, arcEndAngle),
            clockwise: true
        )
        addCorner(
            to: .pointOnCircle(radius: outerRadius - outerCornerRadius, angle: endAngle),
            controlPoint: .pointOnCircle(radius: outerRadius, angle: endAngle)
        )
        addLine(to: .pointOnCircle(radius: innerRadius + innerCornerRadius, angle: endAngle))
        addCorner(
            to: .pointOnCircle(radius: innerRadius, angle: endAngle - innerInsetAngle),
            controlPoint: .pointOnCircle(radius: innerRadius, angle: endAngle)
        )
        arcStartAngle = (endAngle - innerInsetAngle).radians
        arcEndAngle = (startAngle + innerInsetAngle).radians
        addArc(
            withCenter: .zero,
            radius: innerRadius,
            startAngle: max(arcStartAngle, arcEndAngle),
            endAngle: min(arcStartAngle, arcEndAngle),
            clockwise: false
        )
        addCorner(
            to: .pointOnCircle(radius: innerRadius + innerCornerRadius, angle: startAngle),
            controlPoint: .pointOnCircle(radius: innerRadius, angle: startAngle)
        )
        addLine(to: .pointOnCircle(radius: outerRadius - outerCornerRadius, angle: startAngle))
        addCorner(
            to: .pointOnCircle(radius: outerRadius, angle: startAngle + outerInsetAngle),
            controlPoint: .pointOnCircle(radius: outerRadius, angle: startAngle)
        )
        apply(.init(translationX: center.x, y: center.y))
    }

    private func addCorner(to: CGPoint, controlPoint: CGPoint) {
        let circleApproximationConstant = 0.551915
        addCurve(
            to: to,
            controlPoint1: currentPoint + (controlPoint - currentPoint) * circleApproximationConstant,
            controlPoint2: to + (controlPoint - to) * circleApproximationConstant
        )
    }

}
private extension CGPoint {
    static func pointOnCircle(radius: CGFloat, angle: Angle) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: radius * Darwin.cos(angle.radians), y: radius * Darwin.sin(angle.radians))
    }
    static func + (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x + rhs.x, y: lhs.y + rhs.y)
    }
    static func - (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x - rhs.x, y: lhs.y - rhs.y)
    }
    static func * (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x * rhs, y: lhs.y * rhs)
    }
}
public extension CGRect {
    var center: CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: size.width / 2.0, y: size.height / 2.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, you can do it in a similar way to how you'd centre something horizontally/vertically.

You calculate the available space, and how much space the text takes up. Subtract the latter from the former and divide by 2. Then you "shift" the text by that amount. Of course, in this case the "space" we are talking about is measured in degrees/radians.

This means `textView` should also take in the end angle:

```
// pass the same end angles as you pass to the ArcShapes
func textView(_ title: String, startAngle: Angle, endAngle: Angle) -> some View
```

```
// before the ForEach
let firstAngle = fetchAngle(at: 0)
let lastAngle = fetchAngle(at: title.count - 1)
let textAngleDifference = lastAngle - firstAngle
let availableSpace = endAngle - startAngle
let offset = (availableSpace - textAngleDifference) / 2
```

The `rotationEffect` applied to the `ForEach` should have the `offset` added:

```
.rotationEffect(offset + startAngle + .degrees(90))
```

Finally, note that your `fetchAngle` is incorrect. The "H" in "Hello" should be completely horizontal (without `offset`), but you can see that is not the case in your screenshot. The comparison in the `filter` should be `<`, not `<=`.

```
.filter { $0.key < letterPosition }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you! I appreciate the catch with the fetchAngle function!